# Cloudwatch logs my response, but test console says error?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Testing my intent works perfectly in Lambda, but when I test from the Alexa dev console, it returns an error that says speechlet response null. Even stranger, when I go to check my cloudwatch logs after testing from Alexa dev console, my response is there and looks good... any insights? Could this be an async issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, easy solution. I'll leave it here just in case it helps someone. ALWAYS, *return* your response builder.

I overlooked it since I have offloaded the responseBuilder to a separate file, which means I have to return both in the responseBuilder helper file, and return the call I make to that file so it gets to the Alexa service.